# IE9+ not playing portrait video in HTML5 video tag

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, html5-video

For some reason I can't get IE9/10 to play video that is taller than wide, when using HTML5 video tags.

Demo:
http://s.l6.no/demo/video+html5/

The demo shows one video scaled down from 1280x720, which plays perfectly fine in all tested browsers, and one video scaled down from 720x1280 which plays for all browsers **but** IE9/10.

Tested and works for:

- Chrome 26, Windows 7 64-bit
- Chromium 24, Ubuntu 64-bit
- Firefox 14, Windows 7 64-bit

Tested and does **not** work for:

- Internet Explorer 9, Windows 7 64-bit
- Internet Explorer 10, Windows 7 64-bit

I'm using FFmpeg to code the videos to MP4(x264) and WebM(VP8), with the current command dummed down to this:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y -b:v 4000k out.mp4
```

The lack of profile settings would be my first point, but since the other video is playing just fine, I can't see why it should matter.

Any ideas?

Edit: soft rotating the video isn't really an option, as the user is to be able to download the video to play offline. I could transcode an extra version just for IE, but come on, there's gotta be another way, no?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit ugly, but you could add `-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);` to the style attribute of the video tag. However, this rotates your controls as well.

Comment: I considered that option, but the user is to be able to download the video as well, and I don't want to add have two versions of the same video.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the video height.
It has to be less than 1088 pixels.
[More here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797815(v=vs.85).aspx)