# Videos don't play in IE9/IE10/IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-9, html5-video, internet-explorer-10, video.js

I'm using [Video Js](http://www.videojs.com) and the videos don't play in IE9/IE10/IE11, they don't switch to Flash either.

Here is a list of what I did :

- link the videos with absolute paths
- add in the .htaccess the following MIME types for mp4 files and more:

  ```
  AddType audio/mpeg .mp3  
  AddType audio/mp4 .m4a  
  AddType audio/ogg .ogg  
  AddType audio/ogg .oga  
  AddType audio/webm .webma  
  AddType audio/wav .wav  

  AddType video/mp4 .mp4  
  AddType video/ogg .ogv  
  AddType video/webm .webm  
  AddType video/webm .webmv
  ```
- tried to change the `'techOrder'` to  ['flash','html5'] but then videos load with Flash in all browsers (if I could just get them to load, even only with Flash, I would be happy)
- call the videos this way :

  ```
  var myPlayer = videojs('video_restaurant');   

  videojs('video_restaurant').ready(function(){
      this.requestFullScreen();
      var myPlayer = this;
      var path = "{{ siteUrl }}assets/place-video/{{ entry.slug }}/{{ entry.slug }}"
      if(Environment.isMobile()){
          myPlayer.src([
            { type: "video/mp4", src: path + "_smartphone.mp4" }
          ]);
          if(screen.width > 395){
              myPlayer.src([
            { type: "video/mp4", src: path + "_tablet.mp4" }
          ]);
          }
      }else{
          myPlayer.src([
            { type: "video/mp4", src: path + "_desktop.mp4" }
          ]);
      }
  });    

  <video id="video_restaurant" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
    autoplay controls preload="auto" width="100%" height="100%"
    poster="{% for image in entry.backgroundImage %}{{ image.url }}{% endfor %}">
  </video>
  ```
- encode and reencode the videos with multiple softwares (HandBrake, Adobe) and codecs (H264, MPEG-4) even if it works fine with the other browsers (Safari 6, Chrome 31, Firefox 25)

What I get in IE's console is the following error : `Video Error, [object, Object]`.
However if I copy the URL of the video and open it in a new tab/window, the video loads just fine.

Any help would be welcome. If you need more information, just let me know.

Comment: Got a link to the mp4 file on your server?

Comment: Sure, the url is http://foodmovie.be/kamilou/
And the link to the mp4 file is http://www.foodmovie.be/assets/place-video/kamilou/kamilou_desktop.mp4

Comment: This is the same issue as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15970409/740233) where Internet Explorer won't play videos 1280 high.